# unity - play animations one at a time

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I have a coroutine function that looks something like that:

```
// Replacing on start game
public virtual void Replace()
{
    StartCoroutine(ReplaceCoroutine());
}

// the Replacing animation
private IEnumerator ReplaceCoroutine()
{
    // check if the piece has an animation attached
    Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    if (animator)
    {
        animator.Play(clearAnimation.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clearAnimation.length);
    }
}
```

and I activate it with a loop like so:

```
// mixing pieces
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pieces[i].Replace();
}
```

The problem is that the loop goes all at once, and everything animates at the same time. I want to make sure, that pieces[2] for example, will start he's animation coroutine only when pieces[1] got to half of it's time in the animation.

is it possible?

thank you

Comment: you can delay your animation if you want by using the `Thread.Sleep()` method

Comment: @Rakitić No. OP should not use `Thread.Sleep()` to wait for simple animation. Unity will freeze.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call your

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pieces[i].Replace();
}
```

from another coroutine function then wait for each coroutine function to return.
You do that by `yielding` the `StartCoroutine` function call. The code below will call `yourCoroutineFunction` function and then wait for it to finish before running the next loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    yield return StartCoroutine(yourCoroutineFunction());
}
```

I can't tell where your functions are placed but below should work for you. If not, use the example above to fix your problem.

```
public IEnumerator ReplaceCoroutine()
{
    // check if the piece has an animation attached
    Animator animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
    if (animator)
    {
        animator.Play(clearAnimation.name);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(clearAnimation.length);
    }
}

IEnumerator playAll()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        yield return pieces[i].StartCoroutine(ReplaceCoroutine());
    }
}
```

Then to call it, use `StartCoroutine(playAll());`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to control each piece relative to the previous one (half the animation time as mentioned), you want your coroutine to yield *after* each piece operation but do it all in one single coroutine, not a separate coroutine for each piece.

```
public IEnumerator ReplaceCoroutine()
{
     for(int i=0; i<pieces.Length; i++)
     {
         // check if the piece has an animation attached
         Animator animator = pieces[i].GetComponent<Animator>();
         if (animator!=null)
         {
            animator.Play(pieces[i].clearAnimation.name);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(pieces[i].clearAnimation.length/2.0f);
         }
    }
}

void startAnimationSequence
{
    StartCoroutine(ReplaceCoroutine());
}
```

This will kick off each piece's animation sequentially and then wait for half the animation time before looping to the next.  Just call `startAnimationSequence` to start the loop.